# Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined [React Native]

Tags: react-native, connectycube

I have created a session of videochatconference and was able to enter a chat room by ID and view participants. However, when i try to get the local user stream using getUserMedia, it returns an error of undefined function

```js
this._session = ConnectyCube.videochatconference.createNewSession();
this._session.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: { facingMode: 'user' }
})
.then(localStream => {
  console.log(localStream);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

this._session.join('xxxxxxxxxx', userCredentials.id, userCredentials.login)
```

Here is another view of my testing code

```html
const env = Configs.connectyCube;
    const { credentials, config } = env;
    let userCredentials = {
        id: 123,
        login: 'xxxxxx',
        password: '*****',
      };
    ConnectyCube.init(credentials, config);
    ConnectyCube.createSession(userCredentials)
    .then(session => {
      ConnectyCube.chat.connect({
        userId: userCredentials.id,
        password: userCredentials.password
      });
      
      ConnectyCube.login(userCredentials)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        const opponentsIds = users.filter(opponent => opponent.id !== userCredentials.id);
        .map(opponent => opponent.id);
        console.log(opponentsIds);
        this._session = ConnectyCube.videochatconference.createNewSession();
        this._session.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: { facingMode: 'user' }
          })
          .then(localStream => {
            console.log(localStream);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

using:
react-native 0.62.2
react-native-connectycube 3.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in the ConnectyCube docs that it is a must to install react-native-webrtc.

Please check the below: 
https://developers.connectycube.com/reactnative/videocalling-conference